# Counting Occurrences of a Specific Value Preceding Current Value in R Data Frame Column

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame:

```
index <- c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
names <- c("Joe", "John", "Chris", "Joe", "Al", "Fred", "Joe", "John")
values <- c(1,9,2,9,1,3,3,7)
df <- data.frame(index,names,values)
```

I'd like to add a fourth column "running.count" and "running.total"

I'd like "running.count" to populate with the number of instances of a given name in the data frame *with an id higher than the row being filled*. So running.count[7] should be 2 since it's the third instance of Joe (two instance of "Joe" above this row)

Similarly I'd like "running.total" to include the sum of the relevant numbers from values (i.e. running.totals[7] should be a sum of "values" for the relevant rows. I.e. running.count[7] should be 10 since we have 1 and 9 with the first two instances of Joe.

I'm coming from an excel background, and conceptually I just want to "COUNTIF" and "SUMIF" a range from the highest index to index n-1, but I'm struggling to find an elegant way to do this in R.

So far I've come up with essentially creating a new data frame each time that simply has all the rows with a higher ID than the row I'm looking to fill, but this is a pretty inelegant solution for how much data I'm trying to perform this calculation for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(names) %>% 
     mutate(running.count = row_number() - 1,
            running.total = lag(cumsum(values))) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  index names values running.count running.total
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1     8 Joe        1             0            NA
2     7 John       9             0            NA
3     6 Chris      2             0            NA
4     5 Joe        9             1             1
5     4 Al         1             0            NA
6     3 Fred       3             0            NA
7     2 Joe        3             2            10
8     1 John       7             1             9
```